# how to show the details of selected record from the grid in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, model-view-controller, datagridview

I want to display the details view when a user click on a record from the gird. my code is as below:

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<EmpApplication.tblEmployee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>List of Employees</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Create new", "Create", "Emp", new { @class = "Create" })

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(
        Model, rowsPerPage: 10,
        defaultSort: "EmpID",
        columnNames: new[] { "EmpID", "EName", "Address", "EmailID" }
        );
}
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle:"Webgrid-table",
headerStyle:"Webgrid-header",
footerStyle:"Webgrid-footer",
alternatingRowStyle:"Webgrid-alternating-row",
rowStyle:"Webgrid-row-style",


fillEmptyRows:false,
mode:WebGridPagerModes.All,

columns:grid.Columns
(
grid.Column("EmpID", header:"Employee ID", style:"EmpID"),
grid.Column("EName", header:"Employee Name", style: "EName"),
grid.Column("Address", header:"Address",style:"Address"),
grid.Column("EmailID", header:"EmailID", style:"EmailID")
)
)
```

Where/What code I have to add to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add another column with an ActionLink in, something like:

```
grid.Column("Details", "Details", (modelItem) => Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = modelItem.EmpID}))
```

This may work, but I've not tested it.

Further reading:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: No problem. It's amazing what a little use of Google and some reading can do!!